# Change relative path to absolute path in C++ using realpath in Linux

Tags: c++, linux, relative-path

I need to change a relative path to absolute path in linux in C++. I am using realpath, but the output is wrong!

```
char resolved_path[200];
realpath("$HOME/Desktop/SumoSVN/bin", resolved_path);
cout << resolved_path << endl;
```

I am expecting to get this output : /home/mani/Desktop/SumoSVN/bin

but I am getting this!: /home/mani/Desktop/VENTOS/$HOME

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: You probably mean `"$HOME/Desktop/SumoSVN/bin"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shell or environment variables (see [environ(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/environ.7.html)) are not expanded by [realpath(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/realpath.3.html). You need to call [getenv(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getenv.3.html). You could try

```
std::string homedir(getenv("HOME"));
realpath((homedir+"/Desktop/SumoSVN/bin").c_str(), resolved_path);
```

See also [wordexp(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/wordexp.3.html) (and perhaps [glob(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/glob.3.html)). Read [path_resolution(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/path_resolution.7.html) & [glob(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/glob.7.html). Notice that it is your shell which expands arguments of commands.

BTW, the current directory is obtained by [getcwd(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getcwd.3.html).

PS. On some installations with different languages `Desktop` does not exist: it becomes e.g. `Bureau` on French Debian or Ubuntu or Mint systems.